# Not A zip Archeive Expansion File

Tags: android

I am trying to use Expansion Files in Android. All source is givem in google extras . The only proble is that this code is not reading my .obb file.

How o create .bb file:

first i put my all resources in folder then made it .rar and from jobb tool i made this .rar file as .obb file. But when when i use it in my code the output says not a zip file

As i mention that i research on this topic alot but i did not come to the point so thats why i am asking this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your code expects a zip file, you should provide one instead of what `jobb` generates.

Put your files into a folder and use your favorite zip creator to generate a zip file. Put it onto the device with the correct name `main.1.my.package.name.obb`.

Comment: first i put my files into folder then i add this folder to archeive .rar as main.1.my.package.name.rar and then put it on device after renaming as main.1.my.package.name.obb. is this the right way??

Comment: Almost, but don't package as a rar, package it as a zip. rar and zip are two different archive formats.